# Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryContextFactory' Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have written a simple query which was working when I was using .net core 2.1 (I have used Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore)

```
int cnt = adminDb.Role.Where(c => c.RoleId == roleId).Delete();
```

After upgrading to .net core 3.1 I am getting the error below.

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryContextFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
Source : Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore
StackTrace : at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.InternalExtensions.GetDbContext[T](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.BatchDelete.Execute[T](IQueryable`1 query)
   at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.BatchDeleteExtensions.Delete[T](IQueryable`1 query, Action`1 batchDeleteBuilder)
   at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.BatchDeleteExtensions.Delete[T](IQueryable`1 query)
   at Assyst.Administration.API.Controllers.RoleMenuMappingController.SavePermission(Nullable`1 roleMenuMasterId, IList`1 roleMenu) in E:\Source\Main_Projects\Application\PanERP-7\Error\Administration\Admin\Controllers\RoleMenuMappingController.cs:line 365
```

I am receiving this error and I'm not sure what it means?

Comment: Did you upgrade the EF Plus Core package to v3.x as well? If yes, I recommend you to provide a runnable project here: https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues (I'm the owner of the library)

Comment: Yes, I updated Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore version to 3.0.54(right now it is not available),3.0.55 and 3.0.56. But receiving the same error

Comment: In this case, as I said, report it here with a runnable project: github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues so we could try and fix it.

Comment: I have updated the issue in github(https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues/626)